# crate - failure. Using #[derive(Fail)] with non 'static lifetime

Tags: rust, lifetime, rust-crates

I have a `struct` with a non `'static` lifetime, this `sruct` is then used by `enum` that represents my error:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Fail)]
pub enum ParserError<'a> {
    #[fail(display = "Unexpected [{}] got {}", _1, _0)]
    ExpectedAGotB(Token<'a>, TokenKindExpectedOptions<'a>),
}
```

Because of `failure`'s requirement of `'static` lifetime for `#[derive(Failre)]` I'm getting this error:

```
error[E0478]: lifetime bound not satisfied
  --> src/lib/ra_parser/src/errors.rs:18:17
   |
18 | #[derive(Debug, Fail)]
   |                 ^^^^
   |
note: lifetime parameter instantiated with the lifetime `'a` as defined on the impl at 19:22
  --> src/lib/ra_parser/src/errors.rs:19:22
   |
19 | pub enum ParserError<'a> {
   |                      ^^
   = note: but lifetime parameter must outlive the static lifetime
   = note: this error originates in a derive macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

What's my strategy to solve this? Is there way to make `Token<'static>`, perhaps not. Should I `impl` something myself?

Comment: The strategy to solve this is to avoid including the `Token` itself in the error. Instead, include the identifying information you need in owned form. If you really need the token itself, you need to create an owned version of `Token`, but generally that shouldn't be necessary. You can provide a constructor for `ParseError` taking a `Token` and `TokenKindExpectedOptions` and extracting the needed information to store in the error.

Comment: @SvenMarnach You right, that does it and I can conveniently destructure when creating errors. Great!